# How to display application visitor username in React JS application UI

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React JS and practice point of view I am implementing small react application where I want to render a username of a user who has not logged in to react application but he has access react application's non restricted page so I want to get such user's name.

Can anyone suggest me an approach so that I can get visitor name and display it on react UI.

Comment: What do you mean with "guest user"?

Comment: A user who has not logged in to react application but he has access my react application's non restricted page so i want to get such user's name.

Comment: Well, you'd need to prompt them for their name and then show it?

Comment: Yes , prompt scenario have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could fetch your user data using `useEffect()` by hitting an endpoint on your backend which return your user data. Using that, you can render the username.

Answer (score 0):

when the application starts you can display a modal the first time the user signs in to enter their name, save the name in a state and then save it to local storage